ds_oneday_us.sel(lat=i,lon=j,method='nearest') -ISSUES with Dataframe
I have the following code:
for i,j in zip(obs_lat,obs_lon):
    dsloc = ds_oneday_us.sel(lat=i,lon=j,method='nearest')
    dsloc_lat=dsloc.lat.to_pandas()
    dsloc_lon=dsloc.lon.to_pandas()
    dsloc_tx=dsloc.to_pandas()
    
    frame=[[dsloc_lat],[dsloc_lon],[dsloc_tx]]
    
    df1 = pd.DataFrame([frame], columns =['LAT', 'LON', 'TX'])
    print(df1)

Result:

Just want to ask how to get a list of entire column information instead of getting separated information by rows?

I don't understand what you want to do but I see one mistake - you create DataFrame inside for-loo - so you remove previous DataFrame. You would have to concat() or merge() new values. OR you should first append() to lists and later create DataFrame (after for-loop)

I don't understand what you want to do but I see one mistake:
you create DataFrame inside for-loo - so you remove previous DataFrame.
You would have to concat() or merge() new values to existing DataFrame`.
But it could be simpler to create lists before loop, and append() values to lists inside loop, and after loop create DataFrame from these lists.
Something like this (but I can't test it)
# --- before loop ---

dsloc_lat = []
dsloc_lon = []
dsloc_tx  = []

# --- loop ---

for i, j in zip(obs_lat, obs_lon):

    dsloc = ds_oneday_us.sel(lat=i, lon=j, method='nearest')
    dsloc_lat.append( dsloc.lat.to_pandas() )
    dsloc_lon.append( dsloc.lon.to_pandas() )
    dsloc_tx.append( dsloc.to_pandas() )

# --- after loop ---    

frame = [dsloc_lat, dsloc_lon, dsloc_tx]
df = pd.DataFrame(frame, columns=['LAT', 'LON', 'TX'])

# or 

frame = {"LAT": dsloc_lat, "LON": dsloc_lon, "TX": dsloc_tx}
df = pd.DataFrame(frame)

